# What Regular Expression can be used for this?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like: `{filedir_12}somepic.png` and i want to convert it to: `somepic.png` via `preg_match()` or may be something like that. How can i implement this?

Comment: You want to strip the directory from a path?

Comment: 1. Find a regular expression tutorial. 2. Have a go. 3. Come back if you get stuck

Comment: yes but path comes to me like {filedir_12} and I want to cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '{filedir_12}somepic.png';
$str = preg_replace('/{[\w_]+}([\w_]+)/','$1',$str);
```

Comment: that's an overkill - to use regex when you can use a built-in function  `basename()`

Comment: @ZoltanToth, So it's not overkill?

Comment: You guys realize his string literally contains squiggly brackets with the filepath right?

Comment: thank you Walkernoe. It's working. I will approve this answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @MAB Alright, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

[`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) is what you need here. It strips directories (and optionally extensions) from a path:

```
php > echo basename('/my/directory/and/my/file.txt');
file.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need a regular expression for that.  Just use `str_replace()`:

```
$file = '{filedir_12}somepic.png';
$file = str_replace('{filedir_12}', '', $file);
```

**Edit:** If you didn't mean *literally* remove the "{filedir_12}" string, and actually just wanted to strip the directory from a full file path, then use [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

Comment: "A string **like** " the one they gave.

Comment: Give me a break; the question was worded incorrectly.  I edited my answer.

Comment: but string doesn't come always like that. it can come to me like {filedir_14}somepic.png

Comment: @MAB: You didn't say that in your question.  Next time be more clear, and you'll get a better answer.  I've edited my response.  You should use `basename()` if you want to strip the directory from a full file path.

Comment: ok. sorry about that but said in question "preg_match()". sorry again.

Comment: props for answering the question twice - the wording really was unclear, I was going to suggest the same `str_replace()`

Comment: @MAB: You haven't demonstrated a need for using a regular expression in your question, and I don't advise people to use regular expressions when it's not necessary.